# PHP PDO Throws Error while passing an array to SQL Server Table Valued Parameter

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv, table-valued-parameters

I want to pass an array to a Table Valued Parameter in a MSSQL Stored Procedure using PHP PDO Drivers.

I am getting an error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid type for parameter
> 8 was specified. Only booleans, integers, floating point numbers,
> strings, and streams may be used as parameters

```
        $serialtablejsonstr = $_POST["serialtablearrstr"];
        $serialtablearr = json_decode($serialtablejsonstr,true);

        $tvpType = "SerialInfoTblType";         
        $tvpInput = array($tvpType => $serialtablearr);                        

        $con = connectDatabasePDO();
        $sqladdoldstock = "EXEC StoreEntry 
                @type = 2, 
                @ItemId = :item,  
                @ItemDetail = :itemspecs,  
                @guarantee = :gaurantee,  
                @Warranty = :warranty,  
                @Amount = :unitamount,  
                @itemtype = :itemtype,  
                @TenderId = :istender,     
                @FirmId = :firmid,
                @Serialinfotbl = :serialtable,
                @FirmInvoiceNo = :firminvoiceno";

            $stmtaddoldstock = $con->prepare($sqladdoldstock);

            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':item', $item);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':itemspecs', $itemspecs);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':gaurantee', $gaurantee);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':warranty', $warranty);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':unitamount', $unitamount);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':itemtype', $itemtype);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':istender', $istender);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':firmid', $firmid);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':serialtable', $tvpInput, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $stmtaddoldstock->bindParam(':firminvoiceno', $firminvoiceno);

            $stmtok = $stmtaddoldstock->execute();

            $arr = $stmtaddoldstock->errorInfo();
        if(!$stmtok)  
            {  
                 echo "Error";  
            }
            else
            {
                     echo "Success";
            }

            $con = null;
            $stmtaddoldstock = null;
```

I tried to pass array as JSON String with `json_encode()` as `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

I redeveloping/replicating an application in PHP that was previously developed in .NET .

In the .NET version the table valued parameters were passed using Datatables, but I not able to do that in PHP.

I have already gone through these steps [Use table-valued parameters (PHP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/use-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16). But seems like I am missing something.

Comment: Which driver do you use in `connectDatabasePDO()` to connect to the SQL Server instance, what are the versions of PHP and the driver?

Comment: PHP 7.4 and Driver Version : 5.8.0

Comment: function connectDatabasePDO()
 {
  $host="<server-ip>";
  $user="<db-user>";
  $dbname="<db-name>";
  $password="<password>";


        $conn = new PDO(
            "sqlsrv:server=$host;Database=$dbname",
            $user,
            $password,
            array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )
        ) 
        or 
        die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());

     return $conn;
 }

Comment: The database is already created and working fine in the .NET version of the application.

Comment: The link says 5.10 drivers but maybe that's for sql servers dito

Comment: Solved : It was due to the old PDO drivers. Thanks for noticing @siggemannen

Comment: You'd be better off using the stored procedure directly without going through `EXEC`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/use-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16#use-a-table-valued-parameter-with-a-stored-procedure